# How to fix non-shared member requires an object reference Error?

Tags: .net, vb.net

So I'm trying to add Textbox.Text in a class but it's giving me an error Non shared member reference.

My Code:

```
Public Class Produtos
    Public Property demonstracao As String
    Public Property none As String
    Public Property percentagem As String
    Public Property valor As Decimal

    Public Sub New(demonstracao As String, none As String, percentagem As String, valor As Decimal)
        Me.demonstracao = demonstracao
        Me.none = none
        Me.percentagem = percentagem
        Me.valor = valor
    End Sub

    Public Shared Function GetListaProdutos() As List(Of Produtos)

        ' instanciar um objeto Lista de produtos
        Dim relProdutos As New List(Of Produtos)
        With relProdutos
            .Add(New Produtos(Textbox1.text, textbox2.text, textbox3.text, textbox4.text))
        End With

        GetListaProdutos = relProdutos
    End Function

End Class
```

Gives me the error ***Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference.*** whenever I put the Textbox.Text

Any clue?

EDIT:
The code I'm using to add the items to cells.

```
 For Each produto In listaProdutos
            'demontracao
            tabela.AddCell(New Cell().SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER).Add(New Paragraph(produto.demonstracao)))

            'none
            tabela.AddCell(New Cell().SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER).Add(New Paragraph(produto.none)))

            'percentagem
            tabela.AddCell(New Cell().SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER).Add(New Paragraph(produto.percentagem)))

            'valor
            tabela.AddCell(New Cell().SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER).Add(New Paragraph(produto.valor)))


        Next
```

Comment: Your TextBox references are Instance Members of a different class and `GetListaProdutos()` is a static (`Shared`) method. How can your `Produtos` class know or access instance members of another class without a reference to this class? That method is also returning a new List each time. Are you sure this is what you need? + Don't write this thing: `GetListaProdutos = relProdutos`, write `Return relProdutos`.

Comment: @Jimi thanks again for your input. I've edited the main question showing the code I have to add the items to the cells. I think it will only insert the first line ".Add(New Produtos(Textbox1.text, textbox2.text, textbox3.text, textbox4.text))" and not more. let me know if I'm wrong and how to fix the reference error as well.

Comment: Well, you could pass the TextBoxes `Text` values to the Constructor of your `Produtos` class and set its properties with these values, then return the class Properties in the `GetListaProdutos()`, which of course must not be declared `Shared`. Assuming that the instances of your class are created in the class that contains those TextBoxes. -- Note - and it's quite important - that you're trying to generate a Decimal value directly from string value. For your own sanity, set Option Strict to `ON`.

Comment: @Jimi Any clue on how can I do it buddy? Thanks

Comment: I think I have just described it.

Comment: Maybe update your question some with a bit of conext around how you're calling the GetListaProdutos method.  To me, based on what I can see here, the method looks almost pointless as you're already doing most of the work in the Produtos constructor

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want a list of a single product? I think you would want to fill in the text boxes with the properties of `Produtos`. Then add the product to the list. I don't know what the code in your EDIT has to do with the `Produtos`.

If you want to continue with the code you have just reference the form where the TextBox is located.

```
            .Add(New Produtos(Form1.TextBox1.Text, Form1.TextBox2.Text, Form1.TextBox3.Text, Form1.TextBox4.Text))
```

I do not recommend this. The class should be independent from the user interface. Pass values to your class, not properties of the text box. The class shouldn't care where the values are coming from. Do it just like you did the constructor.

Making the list in the class doesn't make sense here. I think you will be better served making the list in the Form.

Your class would look like this.

```
Public Class Produtos
    Public Property demonstracao As String
    Public Property none As String
    Public Property percentagem As String
    Public Property valor As Decimal

    Public Sub New(demonstracao As String, none As String, percentagem As String, valor As Decimal)
        Me.demonstracao = demonstracao
        Me.none = none
        Me.percentagem = percentagem
        Me.valor = valor
    End Sub
End Class
```

Then the code in the Form declare a Class level variable for the list and build your list.

```
Private relProdutos As New List(Of Produtos)

Private Sub AddProduct()
    Dim Valor As Decimal
    If Decimal.TryParse(TextBox4.Text, Valor) Then
        relProdutos.Add(New Produtos(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text, TextBox3.Text, Valor))
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid number for Valor")
    End If
End Sub
```